# Why is my while-loop breaking for specific inputs and works fine for other inputs?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I am new to programming and I am using the book "Programming : Principles and Practice Using C++(Second Edition)" by "Bjarne Stroustrup". I was told to try and write a simple calculator program in Chapter 6.

**I am able to perform many operations of '+' and '-' but when the program reads '*' or '/', it breaks the while-loop and for the life of me, I am not able to understand why.**

I am asking the user to enter an expression and at the end of the expression they will have to enter 'X'.

`operation` is the ***character*** to store `+`,`-`,`*`,`/` and  `double_in` is a ***double*** which modifies a ***double*** `modified`, and then finally `modified` will be the output.

Here is my code :

```
double modified{ 0 }, double_in{ 0 };
char operation{ 0 };

cout << "Expression with 'X' at the end :\n";
cin >> modified;
cout << modified << "\n";

while (cin >> operation)
    {
        while (cin >> double_in)
        {
            if (operation == 'X')
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (operation == '+')
            {
                modified += double_in;
                cout << modified << "\n";
            }
            else if (operation == '-')
            {
                modified -= double_in;
                cout << modified << "\n";
            }
            else if (operation == '*')
            {
                modified *= double_in;
                cout << modified << "\n";
            }
            else if (operation == '/')
            {
                if (double_in == 0)
                {
                    throw zero_div{};
                }
                modified /= double_in;
                cout << modified << "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                throw invalid_operation{};
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of the ouput :

```
Expression with 'X' at the end :
10+20-10*2/3X
10
30
20

Answer : 20
```

Thank you in advance if you are going to answer. Its greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the *actual* input, not a *description* of the input. Also, why are you reading `X` into `operation`? You said the `X` needs to be at the *end* of the expression, which means it would be read into `double_in`, but `double_in` is a `double` and thus `cin >> double_in` would fail.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Done.

Comment: You updated your post to show more code, but I asked you to show the *user input* that the code is reading. Also, why do you have `cin >> modified;` before entering the reading loop? That doesn't belong there. And `cout << modified << "\n";` should be after the outer `while` loop, not before it.

Comment: `if (operation == 'X')
            {
                break;
            }` should be moved in outer loop, instead of inner loop.

Comment: @Jarod42 I definitely agree with that but I am not able to understand why and how is it affecting only '*' or '/' but not '+' and '-'.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry about that. Now I have showed the output too.

Comment: `+20` and `-20` are valid `double`, so your `while (std::cin >> double_in)` succeeds (`while` should be single `if`)

Comment: Mad props for trying to learn not only C++ but programming by reading Stroustrup.

Comment: @JohnDibling Was it a bad idea?

Comment: @Abhay: If it's working for you, then no. If you can get thru it, at the end you'll probably understand computers and programming better than many of the "professional" programmers that have worked for me over the years. But if I were teaching someone programming for the first time, I probably wouldn't start at C++ even. And I certianly wouldn't start with one of the most complex and technically deep texts on the language. Seriously, I salute you.

Comment: @Abhay: Oops. I thought you were learning from [TCPPPL](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321563840/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_uRWXEbV4MVE76 ), not Principals. That's a much smoother path.

Comment: @Jarod42 This was such a great help. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole `if (operation == 'X')` block needs to be moved above the `while (cin >> double_in)` loop, otherwise `cin >> double_in` will fail when it reaches the `X`.

More importantly, `while (cin >> double_in)` needs to be `if (cin >> double_in)` instead, since you need to read only 1 `double` value per `operation` character, and then you can read a new `operation` on the next iteration of the `while (cin >> operation)` loop.

The way you are looping right now, once you have read in an `operation`, you are reading in multiple `double` values, applying the same `operation` to all of them (`+20`, `-10`, etc are valid representations of `double` values), until `operator>>` fails when it encounters a `double` that is not prefixed by `-` or `+`, and then you leave `cin` in a bad state so it can't read any more.

For `2+3*6X`:

- `cin >> modified` sets `modified` to `2`
- then `cin >> operation` sets `operation` to `'+'`
- then `cin >> double_in` sets `double_in` to `3`

  - `operation` is `'+'`, so `modified` is incremented by `3`, becoming `5`
- then `cin >> double_in` fails on `*`

For `10+20-10*2/3X`:

- `cin >> modified` sets `modified` to `10`
- then `cin >> operation` sets `operation` to `'+'`
- then `cin >> double_in` sets `double_in` to `20`

  - `operation` is `'+'`, so `modified` is incremented by `20`, becoming `30`
- then `cin >> double_in` sets `double_in` to `-10`

  - `operation` is `'+'`, so `modified` is incremented by `-10`, becoming `20`
- then `cin >> double_in` fails on `*`

Try this instead:

```cpp
double modified, double_in;
char operation;

cout << "Expression with 'X' at the end :\n";
if (cin >> modified)
{
    while (cin >> operation)
    {
        if (operation == 'X')
        {
            break;
        }

        if (cin >> double_in)
        {
            if (operation == '+')
            {
                modified += double_in;
            }
            else if (operation == '-')
            {
                modified -= double_in;
            }
            else if (operation == '*')
            {
                modified *= double_in;
            }
            else if (operation == '/')
            {
                if (double_in == 0.0)
                {
                    throw zero_div{};
                }
                modified /= double_in;
            }
            else
            {
                throw invalid_operation{};
            }

            cout << modified << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            throw invalid_operation{};
        }
    }
}
else
{
    throw invalid_operation{};
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/9R3Roz)

Comment: Your modified answer was a great help. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it. Thanks again.